# import multiple files and extract specific column in r

Tags: r

I have 20 data file (.txt). My end goal is to chose a specific column (let say V3) from each 20 files, and make a new file.
I tried

```
temp <- list.files(pattern='*.snp.blp')
```

How i can extract V3 from each 20 files and combine (cbind) them in r?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `fread` from `data.table` which also have the option of `select` to select only the specific columns we intend to read instead of reading the whole data

```
library(data.table)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(temp, fread, select = 'V3') %>%
      bind_cols
```

If the number of rows are not the same, then use `cbind.fill`

```
out <- map(temp, fread, select = 'V3') 
do.call(rowr::cbind.fill, c(out, fill = NA))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24) 
invisible(map(paste0('snp.blp', 1:3, '.csv'), ~
     matrix(sample(1:10, 10 * 3, replace = TRUE), ncol = 3,
       dimnames = list(NULL, paste0("V", 1:3))) %>% 
                  as_tibble %>%
                  readr::write_csv(., path = .x)))
temp <- list.files(pattern='snp.blp')
```

Comment: This only works if each file has the same number of rows. How likely is it that all files will have the same number of rows?

Answer (score 0):

Arguably it's better to `rbind()` the rows of the same variable across multiple files than `cbind()` them, especially since `cbind()` fails when the files have different numbers of rows.

In the situation where we need to combine only a single column from multiple files, we can also use `unlist()` instead of `rbind()`.

A complete, working example combining rows using base R can be accomplished with `lapply()`, an anonymous function, and `unlist()`. We'll use data from Alex Barradas' Pokémon Stats database from kaggle.com, where I've restructured the data into 6 CSV files, one for each of the first six generations of Pokémon.

```
download.file("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lgreski/pokemonData/master/pokemonData.zip",
              "pokemonData.zip",
              method="wininet",mode="wb")
unzip("pokemonData.zip")

thePokemonFiles <- list.files("./pokemonData",
                              full.names=TRUE)
attackStats <- lapply(thePokemonFiles,function(x) {
     # read data and subset to Attack stat using the extract operator [
     read.csv(x)["Attack"]         
})
# unlist to combine into a vector
attackStats <- unlist(attackStats)
# use the data in another R function
hist(attackStats)
```

...and the output:

[image]